# PSEXEC: Add User to Remote Desktop Users Group on Multiple Computers

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, psexec

I successfully wrote a script to add a user to the Remote Desktop Users group on one computer through PSEXEC.

```
psexec \\pc-%cn% NET LOCALGROUP "Remote Desktop Users" domain\%fn%.%ln% /ADD
```

This line of code is part of a larger script which receives the variables (%cn%, %fn%, and %ln%) as inputs before this part of the script runs.

Now I want to add a user to multiple computers through looping through a txt, bat or cmd file?

I have searched on Google and thru this website and have not found a satisfactory solution.

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: I bet if you looked at the usage syntax for `PSEXEC` you could answer your own question.

Comment: @Squashman - Thank you. I just posted my own answer. I know that I attempted this solution...and got an error that there was no such user. I have no idea what I typed the first go around? But doing it fresh...It worked. Thanks again. :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
psexec @myfile.txt -e -d NET LOCALGROUP "Remote Desktop Users" domain\%fn%.%ln% /ADD
```

This worked on multiple computers